# How update data from different widgets Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I got a list of **PostItem** with a FutureBuilder.

PostItem got a **like button and a like count.**

[image]

When a click on the post, I go into its details. And I **can like** the post on this screen.

[image]

Here is when I click on the like button in detail screen :

```
Future<void> _updateLike() async
  {
    PhpPost phpPost = PhpPost();
    phpPost.posteModel = widget.postModel;

    if(_isLike)
    {
      String res = await phpPost.unlikePost();
      if(res=="OK")
      {
        setState(() {
          _isLike = false;
        });
      }
    }
    else
    {
      String res = await phpPost.likePost();
      if(res=="OK")
      {
        setState(() {
          _isLike = true;
        });
      }
    }
    widget.postModel.isLike = _isLike;
  }
```

The screen detail update nicely but when I go back at the home screen the post item **not updated the like.**

Here is how I go to detail from post item :

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/post_detail', arguments: widget.postModel);
```

Comment: You need to implement some kind of state management solution to do what you like. Check out for example [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState here is a local for only this widget  and wont rebuild the home page

a simple solution is to try call `setState` after the  `await Navigator.pushNamed`

which will call `setState` for the home page after we close the post page

```
await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/post_detail', arguments: widget.postModel);
setState((){});
```

this will work if you are calculate the like count at the build method or you should re-calculate it inside `setState`

---

a better solution is to not use a `setState` at all for handling a user-data change
and use state management solution like provider with ChangeNotifier, bloc or riverpod
which you will have a controller that will change the data and update the  widget

Comment: Yes, ChangeNotifier solve my problem. Thank you :)